# Draw Video frames onto Canvas in WebView 37+ (Lollipop)

Tags: android, canvas, android-webview, html5-video

I would like to have something like this work in a WebView:

http://54.213.93.173/alphawebm/

When I try to draw video frames onto HTML5 Canvas in a WebView, they don't get drawn and I get this error:

```
glCopyTextureChromium: source texture has no level 0
glConsumeTextureCHROMIUM: invalid mailbox name
```

It looks like there was a discussion on it here:  https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=446512

However, I don't think it went anywhere.  Is this a bug and is there a workaround?  Perhaps I need to set an Android WebView setting?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same bug today.

I could solve it by updating my WebView. With Android 5 the WebView is updated out of the OS. So you just can go to the Google Playstore and update the "Android System WebView" App which can be found here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.webview&hl=de

And whola it is working like a charm. I hope this helps you too.